# Sending http request to solr server

Tags: .net, rest, solr

I'm using `Apache Solr` to index and store my data. My website needs to send ajax requests to get this information, now the dillema is:

> Should I send the ajax request directly to solr server

OR

> it would be better (safer/less coupled/..) to put up a .Net server of
>   my own that would get the query requests and send it to the solr
>   server.

The .Net server would propably expose `REST` option in the same syntax of the solr requests..

Answer (score 0):

I have the solr set up where I have not used .net server. 
I have used standard HTTP query interface.

I would suggest go with standard HTTP query interface, and use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how secure you want your data to be. If your solr server has public ip then making direct requests from Ajax will expose your solr server. If it's an internal/private ip then it does not matter. Also newer version of solr has lot of new features to make it secure and accessible through only your application.